# Required nested while loop in linux :- I have two variable A=(a1;b2),B=(A1,B2) required output like this1=A1 & b2=B2

Tags: linux, bash

```
while read line; do while read line1; do $line | grep $line1; done < <(echo "opt;Mem" ';' '\n');done < <(echo "df -k;free -b" | tr ';' '\n')
```

I have use this but its compeers the send all second variable

My requirement is to run some set of commands (separated by `;`) and grep it with expected output (separated by `;`)

I am using below command:

```
while read line
    do while read line1
    do $line | grep $line1    
    break 
    done < <(echo "m;Mem" | tr ';' '\n')
done < <(echo "df -kh;free" | tr ';' '\n')
```

Output which I am looking for:

```
df -kH | grep m
free | grep mem
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what are you trying to achieve with this script. It's not clear just based on the output what you are doing here.

Comment: You look like you are missing an `echo` in `do $line | grep $line1` and also a `| tr` in `echo "opt;Mem" ';' '\n'`. Remember, run all shell code through [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use nested loops to iterate over two collections in parallel, since as you have noticed it leads to iterating over each item of one collection for each item of the other (n*n iterations when you only want n iterations).

You need to use a single loop in which you will iterate over both collections at once. Making arrays out of your two strings will help you do that :

```
commands="df -kh
free"
patterns="m
Mem"

readarray -t commands_array <<<"$commands"
readarray -t patterns_array <<<"$patterns"

for ((index=0; index<${#commands_array[@]}; index++)); do
    echo "${commands_array[index]} | grep ${patterns_array[index]}"
done
```

You can [try it here](https://ideone.com/WESkW0).

If you need to handle `;`-separated commands and patterns you can use the following instead :

```
commands="df -kh;free"
patterns="m;Mem"

readarray -d';' -t commands_array < <(echo -n "$commands")
readarray -d';' -t patterns_array < <(echo -n "$patterns")

#[...]
```

You can [try it here](https://ideone.com/kPI643).